# Checking if an object is an ApplicationRecord in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Given this

```
module Site
  class Translation < ApplicationRecord
```

Why does this code return false?

```
2.4.0 :094 > Site::Translation.is_a? ApplicationRecord
 => false
```

if

```
2.4.0 :093 > Site::Translation.superclass
 => ApplicationRecord(abstract)
```

what does `Site::Translation.is_a?` respond to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `Site::Translation` object is class, so it belongs to `Class` class, which doesn't inherit from `ApplicationRecord`. If you try the same trick on actual instance of this class, it will return `true`, as you expect:

```
Site::Translation.new.is_a?(ApplicationRecord)
# => true
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to ask if a parameter is a ApplicationRecord or an instance of an ApplicationRecord, so, as you say, asking for an instance is solved... I would know when is a model, if it is possible

Comment: I'm on a stupid bucle... you are right , too complex thoughts means wrong code